# How to Count Instances of Words per Line in a txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I am having an issue counting the number of lines with 'union' in a txt file. I am able to count how many times 'union' appears in the txt file but the number of lines that have 'union' in it are incorrect.

```
# Iterate through file_data and 
# compute your counts in this cell
# ---------------------------------

file_data = []
with open('/dsa/data/all_datasets/hamilton-federalist-548.txt', 'r') as file:

# Hint: for line in file_data:
    
    line_count = 0
    word_count = 0
    
    
    for line in file_data:
        this_line_count = 0
        
# ------------ Add your code below --------------
    #Loop through the array of words 'line'
            
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        file_data.append(split_line) 
    
    #For each word in the array, test it to 'union'
                
    for line in file_data:
        if line == line.count('union'):
            line_count += 1 # Returns 'Lines: 0' - this is wrong.
            
    for word in file_data:
        word_count += word.count('union') # Returns 'Words: 35'
        
    #if it's a match increment this_line_count
    

    #at the end of the line loop add this_line_count to word_count

    
    #if this_line_count isn't 0, line_count would increment by one

# ------------ =================== --------------

print('Lines: {}; Words: {}'.format(line_count, word_count))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```py
#For each word in the array, test it to 'union'
                
    for line in file_data:
        if line == line.count('union'):
            line_count += 1 # Returns 'Lines: 0' - this is wrong.
```

Instead of the above code, try

```py
    for line in file_data:
        if 'union' in line:  # Check if 'union' is present in line, which is now a list of strings
            line_count += 1
```

Comment: It is counting the number of words in the list but not the number of lines that has those words! How would I count the lines where the words are present?

Answer (score 0):

Split returns a `list` and the `count()` function you used works only on `strings`

```
        if line == line.count('union'):
            line_count += 1 # Returns 'Lines: 0' - this is wrong.
```

so in this block `line` is a list and `.count()` is expecting a string

So instead use

```
    for line in file_data:
        if 'union' in line:
            line_count += 1 # Returns 'Lines: 0' - this is wrong.
```

Comment: It is counting the number of words in the list but not the number of lines that has those words! How would I count the lines where the words are present?